# How does restoring a db backup affect the oplog?

Tags: mongodb, tayra

I have a standalone MongoDb instance. It has many databases in it. I am though only concerned with backingup/restoring one of those databases, lets call it DbOne.

Using the instructions in (http://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/dont-let-your-standalone-mongodb-server-stand-alone), I can create an oplog on this standalone server.

Using the tool [Tayra](http://www.jroller.com/DhavalDalal/entry/tayra_an_incremental_backup_tool), I can record/store the oplog entries. Being able to create incremental backups is the main reason I enabled the oplog on my standalone instance.

I intend to take full backups once a day, using the command

```
mongodump --db DbOne --oplog
```

From my understanding, this backup will contain a point-in-time snapshot of my db.

Assuming I want to discard all updates since this backup, I delete all backedup oplog and I restore only this full backup, using the command

```
mongorestore --drop --db DbOne --oplogReplay
```

At this point, do I need to do something to the oplog collection in the `local` db? Will mongodb automatically drop the entries pertaining to this db from the oplog? Because if not, then wouldn't `Tayra` end up finding those oplog entries and backup them all over again?

Tbh, I haven't tried this yet on my machine. I am hoping someone can point to a document that lists supported/expected behaviour in this scenario.

Comment: Have you tried this to see if it does drop the oplog entries?

Comment: @Sammaye, as I mentioned towards the end of my question, I haven't tried it. My point is, when I try it, it will either work or not. In either case I won't know for sure why. If I am however pointed to some documented behaviour, well that's the end of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had experimented with a MongoDb server, setup as a replica set with only 1 member, shortly after asking the question. I however forgot to answer this question.

I took a backup using `mongodump --db DbOne --oplog`. I executed some additional updates. Keeping the mongodb server as is, ie still running under replication, if I run the `mongorestore` command, then it would create thousands of oplog entries, one for each document of each collection in the db. It was a big mess.

The alternative was to shutdown MongoDb and start it as a standalone instance (ie not running as a replica set). Now if I were to restore using `mongorestore` the oplog wouldnt be touched. This was bad, because the oplog now contained entries that were not present in the actual collections.

I wanted a mechanism that would restore both my database as well as oplog info in the local database to the time the backup took place. `mongodump` doesnt backup the local database.

Eventually I had stop using mongodump and instead switched to backing up the entire data directory (after stopping mongodb). Once we switch to AWS, I could use the EBS Snapshot feature to perform the same.

Answer (score 0):

I understand you want a link to the docs about mongorestore:
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongorestore/

From what I understand you want to make a point in time backup and then restore that backup.  The commands you listed above will do that:

1)mongodump --db DbOne --oplog

2)mongorestore --drop --db DbOne --oplogReplay

However, please note that the "point in time" that the backup was effectively taken at it is when the dump ends, *not* the moment the command started.  This is a fine detail that might not matter to you, but is included for completeness.

Let me know if there is anything else.

Best,
Charlie